How to re-render a razor page after closing a dialog in blazor?
I have a main page Transact.razor Page. Inside my Transact Page, there is a button named Add New which will open a MudDialog (AddTransact.razor) where I can add a new transaction. If I were to close the MudDialog (Add Transact), i want to rerender the Transact Page so that the newly added transaction will reflect on the table in the Transact Page.
How do i do that?
I am using blazor server-side .Net 8. Since blazor is a single page application, I want to rerender the page because "refreshing" the page will defeat the purpose of SPA.
What I tried so far is:
Transact.razor
private async Task AddNew()
{
    var options = new DialogOptions { ClassBackground = "my-custom-class", CloseOnEscapeKey = true, MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Medium, FullWidth = true, NoHeader = true };
    var dialog = DialogService.Show<AddTransact>("Add New", options);
    var result = await dialog.Result;

    if (!result.Cancelled)
    {
        await vwTranService.GetAllVwTransactions();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

This is my AddTransact.razor (Dialog)
private async void Submit()
{
    if(selectedUser is not null)
    {
        isVisible = true;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Transaction!.UserID = selectedUser?.id;
        Transaction!.DOCUMENT_NUM = DocumentNumber;
        Transaction.CREATED_DATE = DateValue;
        Transaction.PARTICULARS = Particulars;
        Transaction.AMOUNT = Amount;

    if (Amount > selectedUser!.Balance)
    {
        Snackbar.Add("User does not have enough balance.", Severity.Error);
        return;
    }

    Balance!.UserID = selectedUser?.id;
    Balance.Balance -= Amount;
    await tranService.AddTransactionAsync(Transaction);
    await balanceService.UpdateBalance(Balance);

    Snackbar.Add("Transaction added successfully", Severity.Success);


    Transaction = new();
    selectedUser = new();
    users = new();
    await vwUserService.GetAllUsers();
    await GenerateDocumentNumberAsync();
    Amount = 0;
    Particulars = string.Empty;
    Balance = new();
    isVisible = false;
    StateHasChanged();
    return;
}
Snackbar.Add("Please select a user", Severity.Warning);

}
somehow, it does not work

Where's the part where you actually add anything?  So far as I can tell, you get a result, and then do nothing at all with it.

Presumably, it's added in the dialog.

If AddTransact commits the changes to the data store then await vwTranService.GetAllVwTransactions(); should get the latest list.  Therefore there's something going in you haven't shown.  Can you show your AddTransact code?  Also, you shouldn't need the StateHasChanged if AddNew is a UI event.

@Bennyboy1973 the add part is on the Dialog. Will edit the question and add the method in adding.

Hi @Ben, We call the StateHasChanged method of the ComponentBase class to let the Blazor component know that the component state has changed. So it should get the rerender, pls set breakpoint to the line await vwTranService.GetAllVwTransactions(); in AddNew, if the data has been added. You haven't share entire code of the component and related services, it is better for you to share them with us.If the data has been added successfully,  what if you try await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged), can it works fine here?

Created a method to load the data instead of putting it on the OnInitializedAsync method.
Method to Load the data:
private async Task LoadData()
{
    if (isHr)
    {
        searchResults = await vwTranService.GetAllVwTransactions();
        searchResults = searchResults.Where(x => x.Status == "In-Process").ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        searchResults = await vwTranService.GetAllVwTransactions();
        searchResults = searchResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).ToList();
    }
}

then in my AddNew Task:
I used ReloadDataServer:
private async Task AddNew()
{
    var options = new DialogOptions
        {
            ClassBackground = "my-custom-class",
            CloseOnEscapeKey = true,
            MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Medium,
            FullWidth = true,
            NoHeader = true
        };

    var dialog = DialogService.Show<AddTransact>("Add New", options);
    var result = await dialog.Result;
    if(!result.Canceled)
    {
        await LoadData();
        await TransactionGrid.ReloadServerData();
    }
}

So instead of refreshing the whole page (which would ruin the SPA), I refreshed the datagrid itself to reload the newly added transaction.
